# Opencover: Include namespace/DLL for coverage analysis

Tags: opencover

I've googled around and read some of the stackoverflow questions, but didn't find a hint for my problem. I've a lot of third party DLLs. Since it is painfull to exclude every third party DLL by hand, it would be easier to include specific DLLs or namespaces. Does anyone know if this is possible with opencover out of the box?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already found it (it was stated in docu, see this [link](https://github.com/opencover/opencover/wiki/Usage#understanding-filters)). You can use the `+` at the `filter` parameter to specify explicit includes.